# Logger in Python prints multiple times

Tags: python, logging

I have tried to google up this issue and think that I am calling the handlers multiple times in the script and that is why my logger is printing the same info multiple times. As an example:

My main folder structure is:

```
├── config
    ├── config.py
├── logs
    ├── all my log.txt files
├── src
    ├── models.py
    ├── trainer.py
    ├── main.py
```

For simplicity, my folder structure is as above.

In my `config.py`, I defined the `logging`:

```py
def init_logger(
    log_file: str = Path(LOGS_DIR, "info.log"),
    module_name: Optional[str] = None,
    level=logging.INFO,
) -> logging.Logger:
    """Initialize logger and save to file.

    Consider having more log_file paths to save, eg: debug.log, error.log, etc.

    Args:
        log_file (str, optional): [description]. Defaults to Path(LOGS_DIR, "info.log").

    Returns:
        logging.Logger: [description]
    """

    if module_name is None:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    else:
        # get module name, useful for multi-module logging
        logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)

    logger.setLevel(level)
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s: %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    )
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=log_file)
    file_handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s: %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    )
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    return logger
```

The above code is a standard way of defining `logging` from what I've seen online. Now I need to log my messages into 3 separate `log.txt` files. So in each module `models.py, trainer.py, main.py` I did this:

```py
models_logger = config.init_logger(
    log_file=Path.joinpath(config.LOGS_DIR, "models.log"),
    module_name="models",
)
trainer_logger = ...
main_logger = ...
```

It does create 3 different log files, but the messages are printed multiple times. In particular, my `main` module has a loop as below:

```py
def train_loop(*args, **kwargs):
    # calls the trainer n times
```

I am not sure how to debug this, but as the loop goes on, the logs get repeated more and more, like below:

```
loop 1: training on fold 1
loop 2: training on fold 2
loop 2: training on fold 2
loop 3: training on fold 3
loop 3: training on fold 3
loop 3: training on fold 3
```

I am really confused if it is my loop or, a multitude of issues concerning my logging function.

EDIT: A pseudo code:

````py
# main.py, main script
```python

main_logger = ...
def train_loop(*args, **kwargs):
    trainer.train(...) # calling trainer script's train
    main_logger.info("I am in main script")

# in trainer.py
trainer_logger = ...
def train(fold, *args, **kwargs):
    train_logger.info(f"Training on loop {fold}")
````

Comment: can you show the loop (even better if you provide a complete [mre])?

Comment: @Matiiss I added a small piece of pseudo-code, this is a project of mine so there's actually many scripts and I am unable to decouple to provide an executable script unless I link my script link

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to debug python logging module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65017644/674039)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I found lies in `trainer.py`. I defined the `train_logger` inside the constructor. In that case, when you call `trainer` 5 times in the `main.py` `for loop`, then the `train_logger` is re-constructed every time it passes in the `for loop`. The solution for my case is to define the `train_logger` outside the constructor.